# ionic serve bash: ionic: command not found (after setting environment variable)

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am facing this error after setting a variable for android, I check many questions here on StackOverflow some of them are saying to uninstall ionic and Cordova and reinstall some of are setting up environment variables but I didn't get any solution.

Comment: Show your code please and the error

Comment: i have no error in code

Comment: it's a global setting error

Comment: As in, what command are you running? What environment variable? How are we supposed to guess what you're doing differently than a vanilla install? How do we go about reproducing your error? HELP ME HELP YOU

Comment: ionic serve to serve app .

Comment: "after setting a variable for android" what variable? Right now you're basically just asking everyone to guess. Without this info I'm going to suggest that you reformat your PC and start your ionic project over again from scratch. With info we can actually help you with a more specific solution.

Comment: Which versions you are currently using ?